# Does the GaussianProcessRegressor class in scikit-learn do the operations in a parallelized manner?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian, bayesian

I do not notice any performance improvements when using `GaussianProcessRegressor` on a machine which has 8 cores (16 threads) available or a machine which has 4 cores (8 threads). So I wonder, is the `GaussianProcessRegressor` class in `sklearn.gaussian_process` able to take the advantage of multiple processors/cores/threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the `GaussianProcessRegressor` does not use any sort of parallelization, based on [the answer](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12515) of one of the developers of scikit-learn.